# How can i call generic method without specifying parameter that will return every element in array that matches Type

Tags: typescript, generics, types

im new to typescript and i was wondering is there a way i can make a call such as
`.getComponent<Transform>()` where inside that function i would be able to detect what i entered as type inside <> and check if there are items inside array thare of said type/instance? thank you

.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDonf.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dDhj.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) and try to provide a self-contained plaintext [mre] others can copy and paste into their IDEs to demonstrate your issue for themselves.

Comment: By the way, the answer to the question as it's currently stated is almost certainly **no, this is impossible**. Types are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TS is compiled to JS, and so `foo.getComponent<XYZ>()` and `foo.getComponent<ABC>()` will both compile to just `foo.getComponent()`. The only way for those to act differently is to pass different things to the actual function, like `foo.getComponent(XYZthingy)` or `foo.getComponent(ABCthingy)`. The specifics for how that could work, alas, need to wait for a [mre] to be presented.